# Runtime error in hive udf using python

Tags: python, hive

I am trying to write a custom hive udf in python to calculate experience of an employee, but i'm getting runtime errors, please sort this out.
This is the python script empexp.py

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from  dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

cdate = datetime.now().date()

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    eno,ename,hiredate = line.split('\t')

    hdate = datetime.strptime(hiredate,'%Y-%m-%d').date()

    year = str(relativedelta(current_date,hdate).years)
    month = str(relativedelta(current_date,hdate).months)
    day = str(relativedelta(current_date,hdate).days)

    e = year+'-'+month+'-'+day
    list1 = [str(eno),str(ename),str(hiredate),str(cdate),str(e)]

    print '\t'.join(list1)
```

and in the following I am giving the hive query,

```
select transform(eno,ename,hiredate) 
using 'python empexp.py'
as (eno,ename,hiredate,cdate,e)
from emp;
```

But I am getting runtime errors, here is the error log,

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:207)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]:    An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:697)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:697)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:697)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:189)
... 8 more


 FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20003 from   
 org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. 
 An error occurred when trying  to close the Operator running your custom    

 script.
```

please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file to distributed cache before you can call the function in your script.

```
add file  /path/empexp.py;
```

Then

```
select transform(eno,ename,hiredate) 
using 'python empexp.py'
as (eno,ename,hiredate,cdate,e)
from emp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the file before writing transform....using query in hive.
Is there any problem in .py script???